# confused with strings declared using pointer and that with arrays in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

in the below code:

```
using namespace std;

void swap(char *x,char *y){

  char tmp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = tmp;

}

int main(){

 char a[]="ab";
 //char *a ="ab";

 swap( (a+0),(a+1) );
 cout<<a;

 return 0;
}
```

when the array a is initialized as a[]="ab", the swap function works,
but when it is initialized as *a="ab", it throws segmentation fault, 
can anyone say why?

Comment: Turn up the warnings in your compiler.  If using gcc/clang use `-pedantic-errors`.  `char *a ="ab";` should not compile.

Comment: This is for C but works well for this.  Hesitant to hammer though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char a[]="ab";` is a local non-const array. You can modify non-const arrays.

String literals are const. When you initialise a pointer to a string literal, it points to a const object. The behaviour of modifying const object is undefined.

Even the initialisation `char *a ="ab";` is ill-formed (since C++11), because a string literal doesn't implicitly convert to pointer to non-const `char`.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure C concept, read 5.5 Character Pointers and Functions in The C Programming Languages, you will know the answer. The problem is you cannot change a string constant.